# How to design a mapping for Elastic Search in which a type contains another type

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I wan to design a mapping for Elastic Search, which contains a type A and a type B. and type B has a field of type A.
here is a example from official document

```
{
    "mappings":
    {

        "A":{
            "properties":
            {
                "A1":{"type":"keyword"},
                "A2":{"type":"keyword"},
                "A2":{"type":"keyword"}
            }
        },
        "B":{
            "properties":
            {
                "B1":{"type":"keyword"},
                "B2":{"type":"keyword"},
                "B2":{"type":"keyword"},
                "Field_A":{               //"Field_A":{"type":"A"} not legal
                    "properties":
                    {
                        "A1":{"type":"keyword"},
                        "A2":{"type":"keyword"},
                        "A2":{"type":"keyword"}
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Like c++ classes, first declare A and B,then define a member of type A for B.

```
class A;

class B
{

private:
    A m_AtypeMember;

}
```

Comment: The official document [Object Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/object.html)

Comment: How about using parent children relationship? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is defining a DynamicTemplate where you can specify in the match (*.A1) or more complex match with regex this way this mapping will be applied in both types.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "mappingName": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match":"your regular expresion",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```